# What is the origin of the “- ht” suffix?

Tags: etymology

Old English. What is the origin “ht” suffix? Is it related to “th”?

Examples: bring & brought - strong & strength

Comment: (1) There is no "-ht" suffix. Spelling has nothing to do with grammar. (2) There is a derivational nominalizing suffix _-th_ that appears on some adjectives like _strong, long,_ and _wide_. (3) The irregular past tense form of _bring_ is spelled with silent `GH` representing an earlier velar stop sound that velarized the nasal spelled `NG`. You can see the same thing in German, where the `CH` is pronounced: _bringen, brachte, gebracht_ are the principal parts in German, and _bring, brought, brought_ in English. Spelling is just technology and doesn't affect language.

Comment: I once heard the claim that the "brought" spelling reflects the pronunciation that existed at the time that printing presses were first being introduced -- something like "brogked", where the "g" sound was "hard".

Answer (score 1):

I refer you to the online Etymology Dictionary. https://www.etymonline.com/word/thought

They explain it in terms of "thought"

> thought (n.) Old English þoht, geþoht "process of thinking, a thought;
> compassion," from stem of þencan "to conceive of in the mind,
> consider" (see think). Cognate with the second element in German
> Gedächtnis "memory," Andacht "attention, devotion," Bedacht
> "consideration, deliberation."
>
> Bammesberger ("English Etymology") explains that in Germanic -kt-
> generally shifted to -ht-, and a nasal before -ht- was lost.
> Proto-Germanic *thankija- added a suffix -t in the past tense. By the
> first pattern the Germanic form was *thanht-, by the second the Old
> English was þoht